# Windows Installer stuck on a infinite loop

Tags: installer

My PC had issues and had Windows 10 Home installed, so I gone to Settings, than navigated to Update & Security, than gone to Recovery and hit Reset this PC (reinstalls the PC).
I have a 128GB SSD & 1TB HDD so it all worked until the blue Installing Windows screen, it's left at 64% and shows quickly than just restarts with ASUS logo and under it the loading spinner saying Welcome in white. It just keeps looping it all over again (infinite).
I can access the BIOS (EZ BIOS in ASUS).
My PC model is ASUS ROG GL553VD-FY072T.
I need a solution for this, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the windows restoration is unsuccessful.. just go with full install.. your old serial/license is still valid coz it is the same PC.

p/s: to rescue the HDD content > Hiren Boot Cd .

next time.. you may put you all your data including desktop and my documents stuff in the HDD, and the OS in the SSD.. so that you can re-install your OS (from virus/hang/any disaster) at any time.

Hope that helps.